# Accessing deeper object

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to access the deeper object of an object?

I'm using loops to achieve the desire result:

```
obj = { 'level_one': { 'level_two': {} } }
for k,v in obj.items():
    for k,v in v.items():
       print v
```

Seems to me an aggressive way of doing this. Is there any other way? The keys are dinamically, so i can't use `obj['level_one']['level_two']`

Thanks.

Comment: `The keys are dinamically` which means ?

Comment: You *can* do that, if you handle possible ```KeyError```s accordingly.

Comment: If you need all the values, you need `loop` for which the code you are already having. For getting one single value, the logic you are using to identify the key in `for` loop, use the same. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a recursive solution might fit if the dict can have an arbitrary amount of nestedness.

```
def deep_dict_loop(obj):
    for k in obj:
        if isinstance(obj[k], dict):
            yield from deep_dict_loop(obj[k])
        else:
            yield obj[k]

for value in deep_dict_loop({ 'level_one': { 'level_two': {'foo': 'bar'} } }):
    print value # prints 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you an iterator with all values from your inner dicts.

```
import itertools
values = itertools.chain.from_ierable({v.values() for v in obj.values()})
```

You can iterate on `values` or it is not handy you can force convert it to list:

```
list(values)
```